# Why are my contributions to Go hidden on my Careers profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I've [contributed to Go](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/55df81d37f632e5f45f95b210f862c73a758b124), but when I tried to add Go to the "Open Source" section of my Careers profile, Careers refused with the message "Hidden We couldn't find any commits you've made to this project." Why won't Careers display my contributions to Go?

Comment: Do you have a GitHub account, and is the email address (which is clearly yours) listed as the commit author at https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/commits/55df81d37f632e5f45f95b210f862c73a758b124 associated with your GitHub account? For some reason, GitHub doesn't seem to have linked the commit to any GitHub user. Perhaps you need to associate the email address that you used to make that commit with your GitHub account, or perhaps this is a GitHub bug? Good luck if it's the latter, since they don't have a public issue tracker - you can always email support, I guess. :(

Comment: @Mark is correct - if GitHub links that commit to your user profile, it will appear as one of your commits in the API, so we'll be able to see it's really you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

The issue originates from Github not linking your commit with your Github account, even though the email addresses (in the commit and on your profile) seem to match.

The issue *isn't* due to the fact you are an author and not a committer: we actually handle this case.

This looks like an edge case, I manually updated the project status on your profile so that it is not hidden anymore.

**Original answer**

While you are the author of this commit, you are not *the committer*. The difference between author and committer is that [the author is the creator of the content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18754896/1370722), while the committer is, well, the committer.

[image: git author vs committer]

We unfortunately don't have a way of verifying the relationship between your Github profile and the Go project from the Github API: neither [the list of your repos](https://api.github.com/users/evankroske/repos) nor the [list of contributors to the Go projects](https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/contributors) provide us with this information.

Your Github [profile](https://github.com/evankroske?tab=activity) shows that you are a collaborator to the Go project, but this information is not based on your commits/authoring, but rather on [the Issues you've opened](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/) on the project.

In this case, it would help if Github included the authors in the list of collaborators, but it's not the case and we haven't found a good way to work around it yet.

Comment: Unclear what has been done i.e. why is this tagged status-completed?

Comment: I marked it as status-bydesign which looks more relevant here, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The older report you linked to got official answer from Matt ending with "we'll announce if/when we figure it out" - I failed to see such announcement, can you please update the answer or prod Matt with a sharp stick to do that? ;-)

Comment: The linked question was related to *another* (but similar) problem, I removed the reference to it. This other problem/question has been resolved and the answer updated.

Comment: I don't think it's true, in general, that you can't verify commit authorship through the API. It's perfectly possible with the GitHub API to query by author instead of by committer. For instance, https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/api.jquery.com/commits?author=ExplodingCabbage lists my (ExplodingCabbage's) contribution to the jQuery API docs, even though kswedburg is the committer. The issue seems to be that the author here hasn't been associated with a GitHub account for some reason: https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/commits/55df81d37f632e5f45f95b210f862c73a758b124

Comment: @MarkAmery We indeed use the API route you mention (I had missed it) and the origin of the problem is what you described. Answer updated. Thanks!