# Contributions to repository with squashed commits

Tags: discussion, jobs

Related:

- ["Hidden" We couldn't find any commits you've made to this project. Careers.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244434/hidden-we-couldnt-find-any-commits-youve-made-to-this-project-careers-so)
- [Why are my contributions to Go hidden on my Careers profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247261/why-are-my-contributions-to-go-hidden-on-my-careers-profile)

I have contributed to a closed source repository in which we squash our commits before making a public release.  (We also remove parts of the source code.)  The repositories to which I refer to are here: https://github.com/UNSWComputing

I have added these repositories to my Stack Overflow Careers profile, but they appear as "Hidden" because "We couldn't find any commits you've made to this project."

Can I do anything about this besides making a dummy commit?